# returning boost list from exposed class

Tags: c++, boost-python

I exposed a c++ class to python, one of its methods is something like:

```
boost::python::list getList() {
    boost::python::list l
    ...
    return l;
}
```

it works perfectly, and I dont get any compiler warning.. since I heard that working with containers is a mess with c++/python, I was just wondering if what I did is OK..

Thank you

Comment: *"since I heard that working with containers is a mess with c++/python"* I cannot second that. In my experience, working with boost Python lists worked as expected. Your code should be alright, btw.

Comment: I wonder if the person who said "working with containers is a mess with c++/python" was talking about exporting c++ containers to python, which can get a bit sticky in certain cases. Not horribly, mind you, you just need to be a bit careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way of returning a list in Boost.Python. The "mess" is handled by `boost::python::list`.